# CSS content div with menu div

Tags: html, css, position

ok I am having this small issue with CSS. I have a menu div that is height 100% and needed to use the following to get it to work

```
#menu {
  background:#222;
  width:120px !important;
  float:left;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

on my content area I have this `CSS`

```
#content {
  float:left;
  display:block;
  height:300px !important;
  background:#333;
  width:100%;
}
```

demo [here: jsFiddle - P3Adk](http://jsfiddle.net/P3Adk/)

as you will see the content is under the menu which is what I dont want. I want it to be next to the menu flushed left.

Comment: Does the menu need to be 30px from the top of the page and if so, should the content be the same?

Comment: yes, cos it has a div id header above it

Comment: So like this http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/P3Adk/3/?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try something like the following one:

```
#content{
    display:block; 
    height:300px !important; 
    background:#333; 
    width:100%;
    margin:30px 0 0 120px;
}
#menu{
    background:#222;
    width:120px !important;
    float:left;
    position: absolute; 
    top: 30px; 
    bottom: 0px;
}​
```

Answer (score 0):

Like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/P3Adk/1/)?

Just remove the position:absolute from the menu div, give the content div a percent width, the menu div a percent width (or fixed pixel widths), and a height.

Comment: the issue then is the menu is not 100% height

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#content {  
    height:300px; 
    width:100%; 
    background:#333; 
}
.content-inner {
    position:relative; 
    margin-left: 130px; 
    border:1px solid #F00; 
}
#menu { 
    float: left; 
    z-index: 1; 
    position: absolute; 
    left:0; 
    top:30px; 
    bottom:0; 
    width:120px; 
    background:#222; 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kpjqz/